# For real $2\times 2$ matrices $P$, $Q$, Is $P>Q$ given their eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

> Suppose $P,Q\in \mathbb R ^{2\times 2}$, where $P=P^*$ and $Q=Q^*$.
>
> - If $P$ has eigenvalues $2$ and $4$, and $Q$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $3$, is $P>Q$? (1)
> - If $P$ have eigenvalues $2$ and $3$, and $Q$ has eigenvalues $.5$ and $1$, is
>   $P>Q$? (2)

**Attempts:**

Recall that $P>Q$ if $P-Q>0$, i.e. is positive definite.

- $\displaystyle \left(\begin{matrix}2&0\\0&4\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}3&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-1&0\\0&3\end{matrix}\right)$ has a negative eigenvalue, the answer to (1) is no.
- $\displaystyle \left(\begin{matrix}2&0\\0&4\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}1 \text{ or }.5&0\\0&\text { .5 or 1 } \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}\text{ 1 or 1.5 }&0\\0&\text{ 
  3.5 or 3 }\end{matrix}\right)>0$, where I simply took both possibly combination of eigenvalues in $Q$. Is this enough to conclude that $P>Q$ for all $P, Q$ - is the answer to (2) yes? If so, what property of positive definite matrices justifies this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A = A^*$ and all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.  Thus in case (2) if $1 < \mu < 2$, $P > \mu I > Q$.